# Applying wind function to a ball

Tags: swift, function, swift3, sprite-kit

I have a simple game of throwing basketball to a basket, but I want to add a wind, which affects the ball.

I have made a function:

```
func setWind() {
    let multi = CGFloat(50)
    let rnd = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10))) - 5

    windLbl.text = "Wind: \(rnd)"
    wind = rnd * multi
}
```

and also made a function to launch the basketball with collision Bitmask

```
 func launch(x inX: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
    ......

    // Change Collision Bitmask
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: c.airTime / 2)
    let changeCollision = SKAction.run({
        self.basketball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = self.netFront
        self.basketball.zPosition = self.bg.zPosition + 2
    })


    // ADD WIND!!
    let windWait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: c.airTime / 4)
    let push = SKAction.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: wind, dy: 0), duration: 1)
    basketball.run(SKAction.sequence([windWait, push]))
    basketball.run(SKAction.sequence([wait,changeCollision]))


    // Wait & reset
    let wait4 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 4)
    let reset = SKAction.run({
        self.setWind()
    })
    self.run(SKAction.sequence([wait4,reset]))

}
```

However, I tried to call a function on several places, but the wind doesnt affect the basketball. What am I missing?

The code is here:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    windLbl = (childNode(withName: "//windLbl") as? SKLabelNode)!
    backLabel = childNode(withName: "//backLabel") as? SKLabelNode
    scoreLabel = childNode(withName: "//scoreLabel") as? SKLabelNode
    basketball = childNode(withName: "//basketball") as? SKSpriteNode
    scoreZone = childNode(withName: "//scoreZone") as? SKSpriteNode
    // make sure we get notified of any collisions, including pass-through (for scoreZone)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    resetBasketBall()
    setWind()
}

// put the basketball at the bottom of the screen,
func resetBasketBall() {
    // reset score state
    if !collidedWithScoreZone {
        recordScore()
        score = 0
        scoreLabel.text = "0"
    }
    collidedWithScoreZone = false
    shouldDetectScoreCollision = false

    // the first shot is always at x=0
    var randomX = 0.0
    if score > 0 {
        // x varies between -300 and +300
        randomX = -300.0 + Double(arc4random_uniform(600))
        // randomness increases over first 3 shots
        if score < 4 {
            randomX = randomX / (4.0 - Double(score))
        }
    }

    basketball.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: yBasketballStart)
    // not moving
    basketball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    // ball isn't affected by the physics simulation at all
    basketball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    // stop any running scale animation
    basketball.removeAction(forKey: "scale")

    // make basketball bigger
    basketball.xScale = 2 * basketballScale
    basketball.yScale = 2 * basketballScale

    // not recording touch events yet
    isShooting = false

    // nuke any leftover recorded drag points
    throwPoints = [CGPoint]()

    //
    // Things that will be changed after the ball moves above the net
    //

    // put ball's Z location it in front of the net
    basketball.zPosition = inFrontZ

    // don't collide with anything
    basketball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
}

func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint, atTime t: TimeInterval) {
    // have to start inside the basketball
    guard basketball.contains(pos) else {
        return
    }
    isShooting = true

    addDrag(point: pos)
}

func addDrag(point: CGPoint) {
    throwPoints.append(point)
}

func recordScore() {
    if score > 0 {
        // add the score before wiping it out
        MenuScene.scores.add(score: score)
    }
}

// what to do when the user taps the "<Back" label
func goBack() {
    // record the current score if it's non-zero
    recordScore()
    // Load the TitleScene
    if let view = self.view, let scene = MenuScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene") {
        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        let reveal = SKTransition.moveIn(with: .left, duration: kSceneTransitionDelay)
        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
    }
}

func touchMoved(atPoint pos: CGPoint, atTime t: TimeInterval) {
    guard isShooting else {
        return
    }
    addDrag(point: pos)
}

func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint, atTime t: TimeInterval) {
    // check for touching the "< Back" label
    if touchWasHandledByLabel(atPoint: pos,
                              withDict: [ backLabel : { self.goBack() } ]) {
        return
    }


    // nothing else to do unless we are shooting
    guard isShooting else {
        return
    }

    // add the new point tothe list of drag points
    addDrag(point: pos)

    // need to move your finger to move the ball
    guard throwPoints.count > 1 else {
        resetBasketBall()
        return
    }

    // calculate the dx / dy vector for the ball
    var dx = CGFloat(0.0)
    var dy = dx
    // average the last few drags to get a vector
    for i in 1 ..< throwPoints.count {
        // CGFloat.native is a Double
        dx += throwPoints[i].x - throwPoints[i-1].x
        dy += throwPoints[i].y - throwPoints[i-1].y
    }
    // average them
    dx /= CGFloat(throwPoints.count)
    dy /= CGFloat(throwPoints.count)

    // we always want dy to be at basketballYImpulse, so find out what the appropriate dx value is
    let yFactor = basketballYImpulse / dy
    dx *= yFactor

    // launch the basketball
    launch(x: dx, y: basketballYImpulse)


}

func launch(x inX: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
    // make a 1200-magnitude vector that points just above the net
    var netVector = CGVector(dx: scoreZone.position.x - basketball.position.x,
                             dy: scoreZone.position.y + 1200 - basketball.position.y)
    let netVectorYFactor = basketballYImpulse / netVector.dy
    netVector = netVector * netVectorYFactor


    // limit magnitude of x such that the max angle is 45º
    var x = inX
    if abs(x) > abs(y) {
        x = abs(y)*(x/abs(x))
        print("Updated x: \(inX) -> \(x)")
    }

    // allow the ball to be affected by the physics simulation
    basketball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true


    // average out 2 x the user vector with 1 x the netVector to give the user a bit of a helping hand
    let userThrowVector = CGVector(dx: x, dy: y)
    // weight of helping hand is 1/3
    let ballVector = (userThrowVector*2 + netVector) * 0.333

    // give the basketball a kick in the given direction
    basketball.physicsBody?.velocity = ballVector

    // shrink the basketball down to size soon after it's launched - name this action
    // so that it can be cancelled if the ball flies offscreen
    basketball.run(SKAction.scale(to: basketballScale, duration: 0.66), withKey: "scale")

    // The wind label






    // Change Collision Bitmask
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: c.airTime / 2)
    let changeCollision = SKAction.run({
        self.basketball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = self.netFront
        self.basketball.zPosition = self.bg.zPosition + 2
    })


    // ADD WIND!!
    let windWait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: c.airTime / 4)
    let push = SKAction.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: wind, dy: 0), duration: 1)
    basketball.run(SKAction.sequence([windWait, push]))
    basketball.run(SKAction.sequence([wait,changeCollision]))


    // Wait & reset
    let wait4 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 4)
    let reset = SKAction.run({
        self.setWind()
    })
    self.run(SKAction.sequence([wait4,reset]))

}
// Fetch a new wind speed and store it for use on the ball
func setWind() {
    let multi = CGFloat(50)
    let rnd = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(10))) - 5

    windLbl.text = "Wind: \(rnd)"
    wind = rnd * multi
}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    // check for the ball contacting the scoreZone
    guard let ballBody = basketball.physicsBody, let scoreBody = scoreZone.physicsBody else {
        return
    }
    // it doesn't matter who touches who, so just use array "contains" to handle both cases
    let bodies = [contact.bodyA, contact.bodyB]
    if bodies.contains(ballBody) && bodies.contains(scoreBody) && shouldDetectScoreCollision {
        addScore()
    }
}

func addScore() {
    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    shouldDetectScoreCollision = false
    collidedWithScoreZone = true
}

// overridden touch methods to call our touch method for each touch
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self), atTime: t.timestamp) }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { touchMoved(atPoint: t.location(in: self), atTime: t.timestamp) }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self), atTime: t.timestamp) }
}

// called each tick
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // check to see if the ball is past the net
    let halfBall = basketball.size.height/2.0
    let ballClearHeight = basketball.position.y - halfBall
    if !shouldDetectScoreCollision && ballClearHeight.native > basketballHoopHeight {
        // allow colliding with the hoop
        basketball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = hoopCategory
        // put the ball behind the net in Z
        basketball.zPosition = droppingZ
        shouldDetectScoreCollision = true

    }
    // check for basketball leaving screen in (almost) any direction
    if basketball.position.y + halfBall < self.frame.minY
    || basketball.position.x + halfBall < self.frame.minX
    || basketball.position.x - halfBall > self.frame.maxX {
        resetBasketBall()
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417770-applyimpulse
"For example, if an impulse of 1 Newton-second is applied to the physics body, and the the duration is 10 seconds, then a force of 0.1 Newtons is applied to the physics body."
Does your duration of '1' provide enough force to move the ball?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to edit the duration, but that is not the problem. I was wondering, if I placed the functions correctly and where should I call the setWind() function? I have called it in didMove(to view: SKView) function.

Comment: An impulse ranging from 5 to -5 (?) is very small... How big is the basketball? Why not print the basketball's velocity after you apply the wind, to see if it has changed?

Comment: You'll have to post more code for a definite answer - we can;t see where these functions are called, when the nodes are added to the scene etc.

Comment: @SteveIves I added more code. I tried to edit almost everything, but still no effect.